# How do I set a variable in MySQL 5.5 using JDO and DataNucleus?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdo, datanucleus

As part of my audit logging process, I need to set a variable `@user_id` in my code before running the `INSERT INTO...` statement. `INSERT` will initiate a `TRIGGER` which uses the `@user_id`.

I have tried the following queries:

```
SET @user_id = 5
```

This does not work because `ResultSet` cannot be `NULL` (and this query returns nothing)

```
SELECT 51 INTO @user_id
```

This does not work because again, `ResultSet` cannot be `NULL` in Java

```
SELECT @user_id := 51
```

This does not work because the `:` character is translated into a parameter token when running queries using a `PersistenceManager` and a `Query` object.

So, using DataNucleus, how can I set a variable so my `TRIGGER` statement succeeds with the necessary information for my auditing purposes?

My Java code to run the queries is as follows:

```
PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager(); // My own function to get the PersistenceManager
Query q = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "QUERY HERE");
q.execute();
```

If this cannot be done, what other options can I try to achieve the same result?

*Edit*: I am using Google App Engine, and therefore stored procedures are not available to me.

Comment: Define what you mean by "JDO queries"? JDOQL, SQL, something else? There is no parameter parsing in SQL

Comment: @NeilStockton sorry if I was unclear. I will update my question with clarification, but I mean I am running a SQL query from `PersistenceManager.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "SELECT * FROM ...")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way around the issues described above, so instead used a different approach which I'll explain:

I created a table named `transaction_properties` which has two columns: `user_id` and `connection_id`.

Before each transaction `commit`, I `INSERT` into the `transaction_properties` table with the ID of the user (which I know at this stage), and the MySQL placeholder `CONNECTION_ID()`, which outputs the current connection ID.

In my trigger, I use the following statements to find the `user_id` for this transaction:

```
DECLARE user_id bigint;

SELECT `userid` INTO user_id FROM `transaction_properties`
WHERE `transaction_id` = CONNECTION_ID() LIMIT 1;

IF user_id IS NULL THEN
  SET user_id = -1;
END IF;
```

I can then reference the declared variable `user_id` in my `INSERT` to the audit table elsewhere in the trigger.